# How to cast signed int to 15 bit bit-field?

Tags: c, bit-fields

I have some bitfield:

```
int somefield : 15;
```

I'm trying to convert an int to 15 bit (can be positive or negative).

What is the best practice to do it efficiently?

Comment: Assign the `int` to the bitfield? It's possibly implementation-defined, but that's bitfields for you.

Comment: that exactly the way I did it, but the compiler reports error (in visual studio), but in other machine, it is OK (emacs + gcc).... So it is machine depended and I'm trying to do it independent.... (But all machines are LSB)

Comment: If the bitfield is unsigned, what do you want to happen if the int value you try to assign to it is negative?

Comment: What exactly is the error in visual studio?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851396/how-to-assign-value-to-a-struct-with-bit-fields

Comment: Thanks a lot! The answer there is for c++. Is this part of implementation is identical to c?

Comment: @mibo6700 The accepted answer in that post doesn't use any C++-only features, but it *does* assume that bitfields of type `uint32_t` are permissible, which is not standard. It also requires that the bitfields are unsigned, or the behavior will be implementation-defined.

Comment: "Can I really use an unsigned int in this case - NO I CAN'T!" --> Why not?  Without an answwer to this, I see the question as unclear.

Comment: Note: your bitfield is not unsigned.

Comment: @joop: Note: Whether the OP's bitfield is unsigned is implementation-defined. C11 draft standard n1570: `6.7.2 Type specifiers, 5 Each of the comma-separated multisets designates the same type, except that for bit-fields, it is implementation-defined whether the specifier int designates the same type as signed int or the same type as unsigned int.`

Comment: I think that when it is a negative number, I have to convert it to positive, than to 15 bits and than to make it negative again (2's complement in my case). So I can use unsigned int, but the solution has to be different than "just assignment"....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to convert an int to 15 bit (can be positive or negative). What is the best practice to do it efficiently?

If the `int` to convert is within the range of a 15-bit signed integer, simple use the following code.  It is important not to use `int` without `signed` in defining the bit-field as this is one place in the C spec, it makes a difference.  Without the `signed`, an `int` bit field could be implemented as `unsigned`.  It is implementation defined.

```
signed int somefield:15;
...
x.somefield = 12345;
int y = x.somefield;
```

If the `int` to convert may be outside than the range of a 15-bit signed integer, better to use an `unsigned` field to have portably consistent defined behavior.  It is unclear what value OP wants to store when the `int` is out-of-range.  Some additional code may be needed should the sign need to be recovered.  No additional overhead on writing and maybe overhead on reading depending on coding needs.

```
unsigned somefield:15;
...
x.somefield = 123456;

x.somefield = -1;
int y = x.somefield >= 0x4000 ? x.somefield - 0x8000 : x.somefield;
```

Alternatively, if the value to assign may be outside the bit-field range, insure the assignment does not happen.  Additional overhead on writing and none on reading.

```
signed int somefield 15;
...
if (i >= INT15_MIN && i <= INT15_MAX) x.somefield = i;
else TBD();

int y = x.somefield;
```

Comment: Assignment to a signed type that can't represent the value is *not* undefined. It's implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

chux, thanks a lot!
I've found out another option, and it looks pretty simple too:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int firstletter: 5;
    unsigned int secondletter: 5;
    unsigned int thirdletter: 5;
  } data_in_32_format;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int somedata: 15;
  } data;

typedef union {
    data_in_32_format;
    data;
  } common_data;
```

So, when I'm writing the data itself, I'm writing to the:

```
common_data entry;
entry.data = getint_in_decimal_format;
```

Than I'm printing it in 32 format:

```
print32("%c%c%c\n", entry.data_in_32_format.thirdletter
                  , entry.data_in_32_format.secondletter
                  , entry.data_in_32_format.firstletter);
```

Of cause I need to convert it to char correctly before previous (0-9 => numbers, >9 - letters, so in ASCII it is needed to be +55 to represent 32 bit format correctly (A for 10 and etc.).

Comment: The order of bitfield members is not guaranteed in C++, i.e. the `firstletter` field may actually be the last one and vice versa.